# How do I link files from different folders in HTML?

Tags: html

I am creating a school project website and is organizing my files to different folders. From root folder to css, script, etc... This is the structure I made.

[image]

But I couldn't access my index page from subpages. If I am to go from index to about us for example:

```
<a href="pages/about-us.html">
```

It would take me to the about page. But going back to index, I tried:

```
<a href="root/index.html">
and
<a href ="index.html">
```

But no luck. Surely, it would work if I would copy paste the exact location in my PC. But I will upload this for my professor to see. Also, not to mention the images too that I need to link from a folder up from the subpages. If that make sense.

Bottomline: How do I link files from different folders whether one folder up or one folder down?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Using `../` allows you to jump back a directory (folder) and `../../` would jump back two directories. If your at the root directory you can access a file with `/index.html`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Literally the exact thing I wanna know. I just couldn't find the right words to search. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `../` allows you to jump back a directory (folder) and `../../` would jump back two directories. If your at the root directory you can access a file with `/index.html`. Have a look at the [Dealing with files - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files) documentation for more detailed information.